# How to find stored procedures and functions from all schemas in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to find stored procedures and functions from all schemas in Snowflake?

Table Information_schema.procedure gives details from individual database only. I need to find it out from all schema in system. How can I do it in Snowflake?

Thank you,
Shrini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHOW PROCEDURES IN ACCOUNT;

SHOW USER FUNCTIONS IN ACCOUNT;

Both of these will list all objects that your current role has access to. If run as ACCOUNTADMIN, they will return everything.